# How to access an ASP.NET app though a Virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, visual-studio

I'm developing a web app with Visual Studio 2013. I'm using a Macbook pro and decided to install a copy of Windows 8 on a virtual machine using VMWare Fusion.

I have a static IP Address and I'm trying to understand how I can access this web app from the outside of my home network.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we're going to need much more information before coming up with an answer.

When you say you have a "static IP", where is that IP? On your Macbook? On your home router? 
Is your home router doing NAT so several systems can share this static IP?

What networking choices did you make when creating the VM- specifically, did you choose Bridged, NAT, or host-only?

In a nutshell, the only way your VM will be reachable from outside your home network (without tunnels or VPNs or such) would be if your home internet service isn't using any sort of NAT. Additionally, your VM needs to be bridged onto this network and have an IP address from the same subnet as your Macbook.

It's very likely that this isn't the case; and without the above conditions being true it will be very difficult for others to reach your VM from outside your home network. But again, this is a blind guess. If you can edit your question with additional details we can give you a better answer.